# SQL Server 2008, different WHERE clauses with one query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which takes the same columns but with different `WHERE` clause.

Something like this.

```
SELECT
     alarms.startt, alarms.endt, clients.code, clients.Plant,
     alarms.controller, alarmtype.atype, alarmstatus.[text]
FROM alarms
INNER JOIN clients ON alarms.clientid = clients.C_id 
INNER JOIN alarmstatus ON alarms.statusid = alarmstatus.AS_id
INNER JOIN alarmtype ON alarms.typeid = alarmtype.AT_id
```

and I put the same query in 3 if's (conditions) where the `WHERE` clause changes according the parameter passed in a variable.

Do I have to write the whole string over and over for each condition in every if?

Or can I optimize it to one time and the only thing what will change will be the WHERE clause?

Comment: where is your Ifs and parameters?

Comment: Flagged to migrate to dba.stackexchange.com, as this would be a better fit for the question.

Comment: You should choose one of the answers below to close the question.   This question gets asked a lot, and duplicators could be pointed here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to, you can get around it by doing something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Query]
WHERE   (@Parameter = 1 AND Column1 = 8)
OR      (@Parameter = 2 AND Column2 = 8)
OR      (@Parameter = 3 AND Column3 = 8)
```

However, just because you can do something, does not mean you should. Less verbose SQL does not mean better performance, so using something like:

```
IF @Parameter = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT  *
        FROM    [Query]
        WHERE   Column1 = 8
    END
ELSE IF @Parameter = 2
    BEGIN
        SELECT  *
        FROM    [Query]
        WHERE   Column2 = 8
    END
ELSE IF @Parameter = 3
    BEGIN
        SELECT  *
        FROM    [Query]
        WHERE   Column3 = 8
    END
```

while equavalent to the first query should result in better perfomance as it will be optimised better.

Comment: if by experience you're saying that it is not "bad practice" repeating queries then i believe. that was my solutions also. i wanted to know how old timers approach this, i'm kinda new to SQL SERVER and i'm used to in my mind to try and optimize the code as much as i can so , a legitimate question and thank you both for your answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid repeating the code if you do something like:

```
WHERE (col1 = @var1 AND @var1 IS NOT NULL)
OR ...
OPTION RECOMPILE;
```

You can also have some effect on this behavior with the parameterization setting of the database (simple vs. forced).

Something that avoids repeating the code and avoids sub-optimal plans due to parameter sniffing is to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ...';
IF @var1 IS NOT NULL
  SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE ...';
```

This may work better if you have the server setting "optimize for ad hoc queries" enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably stick with repeating the whole SQL Statement, but have resorted to this in the past...

```
WHERE (@whichwhere=1 AND mytable.field1=@id)
  OR (@whichwhere=2 AND mytable.field2=@id)
  OR (@whichwhere=3 AND mytable.field3=@id)
```

Not particularly readable, and you will have to check the execution plan if it is slow, but it keeps you from repeating the code.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has suggested this.  You can put the original query in a view and then access the view with different WHERE clauses.

To improve performance, you can even add indexes to the view if you know what columns will be commonly used in the WHERE clause (check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Well like most things in SQL: it depends. There are a few consideration here.

- Would the the different WHEREs lead to substantially different query
  plans for execution e.g. one of the columns indexed but not the other
  two
- Is the query likely to change over time: i.e. customer
  requirements needing other columns
- Is the WHERE likely to become 4,
  then 8, then 16 etc options.

One approach is to exec different procs into a temp table. Each proc would then have its own query plan.

Another approach would be to use dynamic SQL, once again each "query" would be assigned is own plan.

A third appoach would be to write an app that generated the SQL for each option, this could be either a stored proc or a sql string.

Then have a data set and do test driven development against it (this is true for each approach).

In the end the best learning solution is probably to
a) read about SQL Kalen Delaney Inside SQL is an acknowledged expert. 
b) test your own solutions against your own data

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way:
WHERE 8 = CASE @parameter
WHEN 1 THEN Column1
WHEN 2 THEN Column2
.
.
.

Comment: Could you elaborate your solution a bit more, please? As I understand the question, the whole WHERE clause may be different.